Usage of the correspondence theorem (ring theory) in a specific context.
Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal of $R$.
I want to prove that $R/I$ is reduced if and only if $I$ is radical.
In the proof of the implication that $R/I$ reduced implies $I$ radical, I use to correspondence theorem, but I'm not sure why I need it.
It “felt" natural to use it here from my intuitive understanding of the correspondence theorem.
This is the part of my proof that uses it:
Since $R/I$ is reduced, we know that $\sqrt{0+I} = 0+I$. (This is a result I proved).
We also know that $\sqrt{I}$ is an ideal containing $I$ (I also proved this). Thus by the correspondence theorem (using the surjective ring homomorphism $\phi : R \to R/I: x \mapsto x+I)$ and by the fact that $\sqrt{0+I} = 0+I$, we get that $\phi^{-1}(\sqrt{0+I})=\phi^{-1}(0+I)= \sqrt{I} = I$. But it is not entirely clear to me what part of the correspondence theorem I use exactly. But this results in what I wanted to prove, namely that $I$ is radical.

How do you prove $\sqrt{[0]} = [0]$ without having $R/I$ reduced (in the second part)? Here $[r] = r + I$

@julio_es_sui_glace I assume that $R/I$ is reduced. So the proof I gave is from the proof of the implication $R/I$ reduced implies $I$ radical.

@julio_es_sui_glace I don't know how to prove if without the assumption that $R/I$ reduced.

I meant the reverse implication. Edit:I thought you put it but in fact you did not, I misread

Please do not answer in the comments, @julio_es_sui_glace.

Shall we add the commutative-algebra tag? that seems to be the assumption.

@rschwieb indeed $R$ is a commutative ring.

(Assuming commutativity throughout, since that seems to be the intention.)

I'm not sure why I need it.

Nobody said it's required, but using the correspondence theorem would help to eliminate the need for an argument using elements, as long as you're aware what the definitions are equivalent to.  Some people find this ability very useful.
Namely,

$I$ is radical iff $I=\bigcap\{P\mid I\subseteq P \text{ and $P$ prime ideal of $R$} \}$
$R/I$ is reduced iff $I/I$ is radical

The correspondence theorem gives you the bridge you need between ideals of $R$ and ideals of $R/I$ to explain why $R/I$ is radical:

the ideals of $R/I$ are precisely $\{J/I\mid I\subseteq J  \}$
and an easy corollary is that the prime ideals of $R/I$ are $\{P/I\mid I\subseteq P \text{ and $P$ a prime ideal of $R$} \}$

This allows you to say that $\bigcap\{P/I\mid I\subseteq P \text{ and $P$ a prime ideal of $R$} \}=\bigcap\{P\mid I\subseteq P \text{ and $P$ a prime ideal of $R$} \}/I$.
If $I$ is radical, then the right hand side is $I/I$, showing $R/I$ is reduced.
If $R/I$ is reduced, then the left hand side is $I/I$, so $I$ has to be equal (through correspondence) to $\bigcap\{P\mid I\subseteq P \text{ and $P$ a prime ideal of $R$}\}$, and so $I$ is radical.
